# Download image in high resolution

Tags: images, download, resolution

I wanted to download this map: https://www.wdl.org/en/item/17278/

With the webpage download option I get the image in low resolution, however with the zoom option I can see the map with a fairly good resolution. Which tool can I use to download the image in that good resolution?

Comment: A zoomed part of an image is not "higher resolution". Zoom just crops the image and enlarges each pixel.

Comment: @waltinator not necessarily. Even 10 years ago my team had code to pull in and overlay higher resolution zooms on demand

Comment: @waltinator I understand that, but in this case when I download the image and I zoom into the text I can't read it, but if I zoom from webpage, the text is clear. So I suppose it has to to be something like what roaima said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Microsoft DeepZoom image.

You can use this tool:
https://dezoomify.ophir.dev/dezoomify/dezoomify.html

to extract the image.

Tool source here:
https://github.com/lovasoa/dezoomify

Comment: Interestingly this produces an image of 3770x2850 pixels while [this version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631814/332764) does 3798x2872.

Comment: @Freddy interesting! The difference is 2 rows and columns per image. Looking at the output from your script you can see the artefact around the second E in the word "RESENA" of images 1_3 and 2_3. (I hadn't seen DeepZoom before, so fetching them like that is neat).

Comment: Yes, it seems 14*2 x 11*2 pixels are overlapping in my solution and it doesn't make sense to put more effort into this. I give up, you win :)

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the html (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) on the mentioned pages, it shows the zoomed image is a construction of various images. So there isn't a "high resolution" image available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the PDF download is in full quality. You should be able to pull the image out of the PDF with `pdfimages`. In Ubuntu/Debian, it's in the `poppler-utils` package.

Answer (score -1):

The native resolution is 1354x1024 so what you get is as high res as it gets.
The zoomed in size is 1263x878
If you wanted the zoomed in version of the image you should right click on the image and click save image while zoomed in. (given that you are using chromium based browser) It does look clearer for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but in this way I can only download different sections of the map and I wanted one image with all the map. How can I solve that?